# Pytest mock local object instance inside a mocked object

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest, pytest-mock

**Problem**

Mock and perform assertions on local instance objects that are not accessible from the encompassing object.

**Minimum Example**

`Executor` is the class to be mocked.

```
class Executor:    
    def execute(self, func, *args):
        func(*args)
```

Mocking `Executor`

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture
def executor(mocker):
    mocker.patch('executor.Executor.execute')
    return Executor()
```

Testing `Executor.execute` is called at once.

```
def test_execute(executor):
    func = lambda x: x**2
    executor.execute(func, 7)
    Executor.execute.assert_called_once_with(func, 7)

    # this fails -- how to test a situation where one doesn't have access to the lambda
    # func2 = lambda y:y**2
    # Executor.execute.assert_called_once_with(func2, 7)
```

More generally

```
def test_execute_with_complex_args(executor):
    def somefunc(x, y):
        x.increment(y)
    class SomeObj:
        x=30
        def increment(self, y):
            self.x += y
 
    obj = SomeObj()
    executor.execute(somefunc, obj, 7)
    Executor.execute.assert_called_once()

    # this is assuming we have access to somefunc and obj instances
    Executor.execute.assert_called_once_with(somefunc, obj, 7)

    # how to verify that increment was called with arg 7?
    # somefunc and obj are instances that are not accessible?
```

**Why is this important/what is the need for such a round-about testing?**

I am testing a database client that uses `SqlAlchemy`. I want to verify a query is executed with the right arguments. A typical function in the client looks like this:

```
def get_job(self, job_id: UUID) -> Job:
        return run_transaction(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine),
                               lambda s: copy(s.query(Job).filter(Job.id == job_id).one()))
```

`sessionmaker` and `run_transaction` are mockable and can be tested but I want to verify the `Session.query` method is called appropriately.

Comment: Youe `Executer` example is not testing your code - it just tests the mock itself, because you mock the function you want to test. Mocking is for components that you _don't_ want to test, and don't want executed in the test (though  you may test that they are executed). If you want to test that `Session.query` is called in `run_transaction`, you have to mock `Session.query` (and not `run_transaction`) while running `get_job` in your test.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen You are correct, I should have said `Executor` is the class to be mocked. Regarding "you have to mock `Session.query`: How do I do that? Doing something like `mocker.patch('Session.query')` and then asserting `Session.query.assert_called_once()` doesn't work because `SqlAlchemy` uses a local instance of the `Session` class.

Comment: Mocking should still work, though you may have to adapt your patch string, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).